# Workaround to append attaching elements in reverse order when sorting

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to sort so that odd numbers in a list appeart first and evens appear last, but i need evens to be the same position to how they were pre sort, is there a simple workaround to this?

```
let rec first_odd list = match list with
| [] -> []
| h::t when h mod 2==0 -> first_odd t@[h]
| h::t -> h::first_odd t;;

first_odd[3;1;7;3;4;5;4;3;6;-1;0;3];;
first_odd[1;0;1;5;6;6;1;10;-8;4; -9];;
```

Comment: By the way, do you intend that `odd list` be sorted and `even list` not sorted? Since it is mentioned, `...i need evens to be the same position to how they were pre sort...`? How about the `odds`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `List.stable_sort`, which implements a merge sort, with a function that compares whether or not each element is odd or even:

```
let first_odd =
  List.stable_sort
    (fun a b -> compare (a mod 2 = 0) (b mod 2 = 0))
```

```
first_odd[3;1;7;3;4;5;4;3;6;-1;0;3];;
- : int list = [3; 1; 7; 3; 5; 3; -1; 3; 4; 4; 6; 0]

first_odd[1;0;1;5;6;6;1;10;-8;4; -9];;
- : int list = [1; 1; 5; 1; -9; 0; 6; 6; 10; -8; 4]
```

Comment: Alternatively, `let a, b = List.partition (fun x -> x mod 2 <> 0) lst in a @ b`

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework assignment, so I'll just make a few comments.

First, the expression `list @ [elt]` has a very bad look to it. If you repeat this for n elements of a list, it has complexity of n^2, because it takes linear time to add to the end of a list. Furthermore, it's necessary to replicate the whole list to add an element to the end. So it's definitely something to avoid.

Second, you can just use `List.stable_sort` if you write a comparison function that gives the order you desire. This will be a lot faster than your current solution (because it will be n log n rather than n^2).

Third, if you want to work with your current method, I would keep two lists and combine them at the end.

Comment: For the third method, Is this possible with having 3 nested functions? One creates a list of odds, one of evens and the last combines both?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do it that way. I would probably just use one helper function with two list parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As an academic exercise, it may help to see this implemented in terms of a fold. When using a fold, the initial state is crucial. Let's use two lists in a tuple. One for odds, and one for evens.

Each iteration we consider the initial value and the first element in the list. The function we provide uses that information to provide an updated initial value for the next iteration, which considers the next element in the list.

```
let list1 = [3; 1; 7; 3; 4; 5; 4; 3; 6; -1; 0; 3]
let list2 = [1; 0; 1; 5; 6; 6; 1; 10; -8; 4; -9]

let sort lst =
  List.fold_left (* function *) ([], []) lst
```

Now, we just need a function that updates the initial value on each iteration. If the value is even, we'll tack it into the front of the evens list. Otherwise, onto the front of the odds list.

```
let sort lst =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (odds, evens) x -> 
       if x mod 2 = 0 then (odds, x :: evens)
       else (x :: odds, evens)) 
    ([], []) 
    lst
```

If we test this with `list2`:

```
# sort list2;;
- : int list * int list = ([-9; 1; 5; 1; 1], [4; -8; 10; 6; 6; 0])
```

The two lists are backwards. We can fix this with `List.rev`.

```
let sort lst =
  let odds, evens = 
    List.fold_left 
      (fun (odds, evens) x -> 
         if x mod 2 = 0 then (odds, x :: evens)
         else (x :: odds, evens)) 
      ([], []) lst
  in
  List.(rev odds, rev evens)
```

```
# sort list2;;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 1; 5; 1; -9], [0; 6; 6; 10; -8; 4])
```

Essentially we've now reinvented `List.partition`.

Now, we just need to concatenate those two lists.

```
let sort lst =
  let odds, evens = 
    List.fold_left 
      (fun (odds, evens) x -> 
         if x mod 2 = 0 then (odds, x :: evens)
         else (x :: odds, evens)) 
      ([], []) 
      lst
  in
  List.(rev odds @ rev evens)
```

```
# sort list2;;
- : int list = [1; 1; 5; 1; -9; 0; 6; 6; 10; -8; 4]
```