# How to get a list with odd numbers first, then even numbers attached at end. OCaml

Tags: function, ocaml

I have to transform a list into a list, where the odds come first and evens after.
I have the logic around it but am unsure how to write the code correctly.

The list should be split into 2 lists, one of all odds and one of all evens. Then join the evens to the odds with odds @ evens and output the final list.
My code currently is :

```
let oddfirst = isOdd @ isEven;; 
    let isOdd list= List.allOdd (fun x -> x mod 2!= 0) list;;
    let isEven list= List.allEven (fun y -> y mod 2= 0) list;;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current code?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801979/workaround-to-append-attaching-elements-in-reverse-order-when-sorting). You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the [`List.partition`](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALpartition) function:

```
let oddFirst l =
  let (even, odd ) = List.partition (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) l in
  odd @ even;;

oddFirst list
```

Answer (score 1):

OCaml files are read top to bottom. You are concatenating two elements that are not defined. `isOdd` and `isEven` are not lists, they're functions that take `int list` and return I don't know what since you're using functions that don't exist in the `List` module.

Your code should look like:

```ml
let oddfirst l = 
  let isOdd = List.<find_the_function> (fun x -> x mod 2 <> 0) l in 
  let isEven = List.<find_the_function> (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) l in 
  isOdd @ isEven
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way i can work it out without the  List.function, because im not sure what to put there.

Comment: And is the l after oddfirst a decleration for a list?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out List.filter works best for me. Here is the solution:

```
let oddfirst l = 
  let isOdd = List.filter (fun x -> x mod 2 != 0) l in 
  let isEven = List.filter (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) l in 
  isOdd @ isEven
```

Comment: a small hint, use `<>` for not equal in OCaml, as `!=` stands for not physically equal, which is a different thing. This is a classical false friend when you came from another language.